# How to map a JavaScript function returning an async iterator in Dart using package:js?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webapi, dart-js-interop

I'd like to use the [`window.showDirectoryPicker()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker) from Dart/Flutter. Using it from JavaScript to allow a user to select a directory and then list the contents of it works like this:

```
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
  console.log(entry.name);
}
```

The docs for `FileSystemDirectoryHandle.values()` say it returns "a new Array Iterator containing the values for each index in the `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` object." It doesn't say specifically, though it appears to be an *async* iterator as enumerating it requires `await for`.

I'm trying to create bindings to call this from Dart. I expect that my binding should return a `Stream<FileSystemHandle>` although I can't find any examples or docs about doing this. I've tried many combinations of things, though here's what I have now:

```
@JS()
library js_lib;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';

Future<FileSystemDirectoryHandle> showDirectoryPicker() =>
    promiseToFuture(callMethod(window, 'showDirectoryPicker', []));

@JS()
abstract class FileSystemDirectoryHandle extends FileSystemHandle {
  external Stream<FileSystemHandle> values();
}

@JS()
abstract class FileSystemHandle {
  String get name;
}

@JS()
abstract class FileSystemFileHandle extends FileSystemHandle {}
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
final dirHandle = await showDirectoryPicker();
await for (final item in dirHandle.values()) {
  print(item.name);
}
```

However this fails like with the error:

> Error: Expected a value of type 'Stream', but got one of type 'NativeJavaScriptObject'

I suspect I may need something to convert the JS iterator to a Dart stream (similar to the `promiseToFuture` call I have), although I can't find a way to do that (I'm also unable to add methods to `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` that aren't `external`.

Comment: A Flutter Developer is asking a question?

Comment: My contributions are mostly tooling focused - there's a lot more I don't know than I know :-)

Comment: To be honest it was a very motivating statement for some people like me. I didn't understand the question though (can't even think of matching your level), but I'm sure this question was worthy to ask. But again, you were probably the one who could answer it and you just did. +1 and thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This seems to work in `build_runner serve` but not `build_runner serve --release`. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44692) to determine if this is a bug or this is the wrong way to do this.

---

After realising the async iterators in JS are just iterators where `next()` returns a promise, I was able to write a small function that just invoked the method manually and yielded in an `async*` function:

```
extension FileSystemDirectoryHandleExtensions on FileSystemDirectoryHandle {
  Stream<FileSystemHandle> values() =>
      _asyncIterator<FileSystemHandle>(callMethod(this, 'values', []));
}

Stream<T> _asyncIterator<T>(jsIterator) async* {
  while (true) {
    final next = await promiseToFuture(callMethod(jsIterator, 'next', []));
    if (getProperty(next, 'done')) {
      break;
    }
    yield getProperty(next, 'value');
  }
}
```

This is called using the original Dart code above, and prints the filenames as desired.

Comment: I was wondering if you have successfully managed to run: `showDirectoryPicker` and e.g. read a list of files within a folders. Do you have an example of that?